# UTF8Type vs. ByteType Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

could you help me find out the reasons behind why "user" column family is compared with UTF8Type not ByteType and username with BytesType not UTF8Type in this article: http://www.rackspacecloud.com/blog/2010/05/12/cassandra-by-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good reason. Today good style would recommend making both UTF8Type.  It only matters for validation though; even if column ordering mattered (which it does not on these CFs) utf8 sorts the same as lexical byte ordering anyway.

Also: wouldn't commenting directly on the article be more useful for other readers?

Comment: probobly would but don't know how fast would get a response don't you reckon?